# How to modify style of date range PrimeNg's p-calendar?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I am trying to understand how to modify the primeng p-calendar style for range selection, but can't understand.
I want to show first and last item with the style p-highlight. And middle part of range must be another color. Something like this:
[image]

I'm tried something like this, but it's wrong:

```
.p-datepicker table td > span.p-highlight:first-child {
color: var(--datepicker-body-text-color);
background: var(--datepicker-body-selected-color);
```

}

Is it possible to do this with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I did it something like this:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="date" let-date>
      <span
        class="calendar-item"
        [ngClass]="{
          endpoint:
            date.day ===
              (dateRangePickerControl.value &&
              dateRangePickerControl.value[0]
                ? dateRangePickerControl.value[0].getDate()
                : null) ||
            date.day ===
              (dateRangePickerControl.value &&
              dateRangePickerControl.value[1]
                ? dateRangePickerControl.value[1].getDate()
                : null)
        }"
        >{{ date.day }}</span
      >
    </ng-template>
```

The "endpoint" class is the one by which you can control styling of start and end date. By setting back color for p-highlight you can control all selected cells.